# How to add SharePoint 2010 Lists.asmx as a reference to Visual Studio 2013 project?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, soap

I am doing the following steps:

1. Add Service Reference
2. Advanced
3. Add Web Reference
4. Enter URL and hit Go (I have tried this "https://spsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl" and this "https://spsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx" for the URL)
5. Enter credentials in login screen (I then see either the method definition through HTML view or the WSDL XML definition on the left side of the screen)

After that, instead of having the ability to Add Reference based on the web services definition, I get the message: The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

Is this because I'm using VS2013? I have seen several articles online do exactly those steps and they can Add Reference once they get to the point that I got.